# Is Spring - SpEL vulnerable?

Tags: spring, security, spring-el

I came across an article [Open source library with vulnerabilities](http://www.networkworld.com/news/2012/032612-open-source-vulnerabilities-257645.html).

This article states that
"Spring Expression Language (SpEL) could be exploited through HTTP parameter submissions that would allow attackers to get sensitive system data, application and user cookies."

Can someone shed more light on this, please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout this Aspect Security/Minded Security [evaluation of SpEL](http://www.mindedsecurity.com/fileshare/ExpressionLanguageInjection.pdf) ([google docs link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dc1xxO8UMFaGLOwgkykYdghGWm_2Gn0iCrxFsympqcE/edit?hl=en_US)) which the article you link to is probably referring (for the specific case of SpEL).

They describe how certain spring JSP tags double evaluate EL expressions.  In these cases it may be possible for the user to submit data to the server in the form of SpEL e.g. as a request parameter with value `${bean.val}` (URL encoded)

```
http://...?exp=$%7Bbean.val%7D
```

Inside JSP pages, the expression `${param.exp}` will be resolved to the text `${bean.val}` which by itself is safe.  If however, that expression resides within an attribute of a spring JSTL tag, that resolved value may be evaluated again e.g. in the `spring:message` tag:

```
<spring:message message="${param.exp}" />
```

will result in the value `${bean.val}` being passed through to the `spring:message` tag which will evaluate the `bean.getVal()` method.  Hence we now have code submitted by the client and being run on the server.

Comment: please see the much higher voted answer below, which is the actual one

Comment: @blackdrag thanks, I have already read it.  Both this post and Pieter's provide two different answers to the original question "Can someone shed more light on this, please?".  This answer (almost a year old now) hopefully provides some detail into what the vulnerability actually was, whilst Pieter's answer describes SpringSources history in dealing with it and the versions of spring in which this issue is resolved.  IMO they both "shed light" in different ways and both are "actual" answers.

Comment: I agree, they both shed light on the issue. Only that it is fixed since before 2012. The most valuable information, that the report was already outdated at the time this was asked, is missing. That's why I don't consider the answer as "actual" anymore.

Answer (score 27):

The discovery by Aspect Security was found in January 2013, but the fix that SpringSource published was made available back in 2011 when this was first discovered. Dan Amodio of Aspect Security informed SpringSource about the possibility of remote code execution.

SpringSource updated our security report 12-06-2012 with Aspect Security’s finding – but the fix/mitigation listed in the original advisory is still applicable: http://support.springsource.com/security/cve-2011-2730

This vulnerability only affects Spring Framework versions:

• 3.0.0 to 3.0.5  -- upgrading to 3.0.6 here would solve the issue.
• 2.5.0 to 2.5.6.SEC02 (community releases)  -- upgrading to 2.5.6.SEC03 here would solve the issue.
• 2.5.0 to 2.5.7.SR01 (subscription customers) -- upgrading to 2.5.7.SR02 here would solve the issue.

This has been fixed in all versions going forward – the current release of SpringFramework is 3.2, released in Dec 2012.

Thanks,

-Pieter (SpringSource)